# Self referential relationship including a relationship attribute

Tags: python, entity-framework, sqlalchemy, self-reference

## Situation

I have the Self-Referential Many-to-Many Relationship (almost identical to the sqlalchemy manual entry of the same heading). This relationship is governed by the table `entity_weights`. This code works!

## Question

How do I include an attribute in class `Entity` representing the table column `entity_weights.weight`. Lets say the attribute would be called `Entity.child_weights`. It is important that the rank of `Entity.child_entities` and `Entity.child_weights` are identical.

```
entity_weights = Table('entity_weights', Base.metadata,
    Column('id',Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('parent_entity_id',Integer, ForeignKey('entity.id')),
    Column('entity_id',Integer, ForeignKey('entity.id')),
    Column('weight',Float))


class Entity(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'entity'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    domicile_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('domicile.id'))
    entity_type = Column('type',Enum('asset','institution','model'))
    source_table_id = Column(Integer)
    child_entities = relationship('Entity',
                        secondary=entity_weights,
                        primaryjoin=id==entity_weights.c.parent_entity_id,
                        secondaryjoin=id==entity_weights.c.entity_id,
                        backref='parent_entity_id'
                        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanest solution I've found for this scenario is to break up the `child_entities` relationship by adding `entity_weights` as a one-to-many relationship on `Entity` and use an [association proxy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html) to proxy the `weight` value as well as the remote side of the many-to-many relationship:

```
class EntityWeight(Base):
    __tablename__ = "entity_weights"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_entity_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('entity.id'))
    entity_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('entity.id'))
    weight = Column(Float)
    entity = relationship("Entity", primaryjoin=lambda: EntityWeight.entity_id == Entity.id)

class Entity(Base):
    ...
    _child_weights = relationship(EntityWeight, primaryjoin=id == EntityWeight.parent_entity_id)
    child_weights = association_proxy("_child_weights", "weight")
    child_entities = association_proxy("_child_weights", "entity")
```